# how to validate map items with custom key using gtest?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, googletest

I've written a custom key for my map

```
struct custom_key {
  string id;
  string sector;

  bool operator==(const custom_key& other) {
    // I'm needed by gtest
    return id == other.id && sector == other.sector;
  }

};
```

to that I've added the less then overload

```
namespace std
{
  template<> struct less<custom_key>
  {
    bool operator() (const custom_key& lhs, const custom_key& rhs) const
    {
      return lhs.id < rhs.id;
    }
  };
}
```

I've also defined my matcher

```
MATCHER_P(match_eq, value, "")
{
    return arg == value;
}
```

with that i've tried to write a test

```
EXPECT_CALL(
  *stats_,
  stats(
    AllOf(
      Field(&data,
        Contains(
          Pair(
            custom_key{"id", "name"},
            match_eq("expected_value")
          )
        )
      )
   )
);
```

I've run it against

```
std::map<custom_key, std::string> my_map = { {"id", "name"}, "expected_value" }
```

and gtest is saying he did not find the match. And I'm lost.
I can not find debugging it any help due to extensive use of templates in impl of gtest.
Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide [mcve], in particular enough code to be able to run this `EXPECT_CALL` (and reproduce the error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue I see here is that your `operator==` has no `const` qualifier. You need something like this:

```
bool operator==(const custom_key& other) const {
    // I'm needed by gtest
    return id == other.id && sector == other.sector;
  }
```

Next one,

> I've run it against std::map<custom_key, std::string> my_map = { {"id", "name"}, "expected_value" }

This will not compile, you need to have extra braces to initialize `std::pair<custom_key, std::string>` which will initialize `std::map` after that.

You are not explaining all checks which you are performing in EXPECT_CALL, but looks like you got general idea of container validation using [Contains](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/matchers.html#container-matchers).

Complete solution for std::map validation will looks like:

```
#include <map>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
using namespace ::testing;
using namespace std;

struct custom_key {
    string id;
    string sector;

    bool operator==(const custom_key& other) const
    {
        // I'm needed by gtest
        return id == other.id && sector == other.sector;
    }
};

namespace std {
template <>
struct less<custom_key> {
    bool operator()(const custom_key& lhs, const custom_key& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.id < rhs.id;
    }
};
}

TEST(MapValidation, 67704150)
{
    map<custom_key, string> my_map { { { "id", "name" }, "expected_value" } };
    EXPECT_THAT(my_map, Contains(Pair(custom_key { "id", "name" }, "expected_value")));
}
```

Also I don't see why you need matcher here.

Comment: Thank you for this, I'm not that familiar with advanced gtest solution and that's something I was trying to figure out with trial and error. Maybe matcher is overhead to be cut out.